# Ranking or filling lists created with plyr

Tags: r, dplyr

please consider the following.

With `dlply` from the `plyr` package I split a dataframe into lists according to "Subject IDs" and another variable indicating a time sequence. I receive lists named by the ID and the time sequence (10.1, 10.2, 10.3 etc.).

With `ldply` I applied a function to the previous operation and receive a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
> db <- data.frame(ID = c(10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 11.2, 11.3, 12.2))
> db
    ID
1 10.1
2 10.2
3 10.3
4 11.2
5 11.3
6 12.2
```

I now want to introduce a column based on the IDs always starting with '1'. The desired outcome would look like this:

```
> result <- data.frame(ID = c(10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 11.2, 11.3, 12.2),
+                      rank = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1))
> result
    ID rank
1 10.1    1
2 10.2    2
3 10.3    3
4 11.2    1
5 11.3    2
6 12.2    1
```

It tried to again use `dlply` to create lists according to the ID and then fill these lists in the column called 'rank'. But because one list for each ID would be created (i.e. one for 10.1, 10.2, 10.3) I would first need to use

```
db$pure.ID <- substr(db$ID, 1, nchar(db$ID) - 2)
```

to create lists per ID instead of per 'sub-'ID. But then I still don't know how to fill the column 'rank' in these lists.

I am sure that there is a better way to do this and maybe I don't fully understand the idea of the `plyr` package (I guess one could do all operations in one go).

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ID variable is numeric, as indicated in your `db`, you could consider rounding  the ID variable down and using that as a grouping variable. Then you could add a counter with `row_number()`

```
db %>% group_by(floor(ID)) %>% mutate(rank = row_number()) %>% 
                ungroup() %>% select( - `floor(ID)`)

#      ID  rank
# 1  10.1     1
# 2  10.2     2
# 3  10.3     3
# 4  11.2     1
# 5  11.3     2
# 6  12.2     1
```